# How to fix PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in my android application

Tags: java, android, libgdx

OK up until I started integrating FireBase my android app would load for debugging  google services and other things. When I started integrating FireBase and AdMob I got the above mentioned error I am adding both manifests. I am using Android Studio 2.1.1 and Libgdx this is my Main manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.allen.howlers.game"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.allen.howlers.game.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

This is my secondary manifest from BaseGameUtils:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.games.basegameutils"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"  />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are any of your string resources in the manifest translatable?

Comment: except for the package name, they are all google play ids

Comment: Are you getting anything in your logcat?

Comment: No it just says the build was successful for android the problem seems to be when it is being copied to my debug device. This is the very first time it has happened on any project.